# How to use provider correctly while I'm tryng to set a profile management?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, profile, provider

I'm trying to use provider to get different informations about the user, (actually the uid) but it's not working because the `.auth`  isn't defined for the type 'AuthClass', by the way I put AuthClass because my code is there but I'm not sure it's the good class. I looked for solutions and they say that we have to use our provider auth class but I don't know what is it either where I can find. Maybe you can help me

This is my code ( the .auth is underlined in red ):

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget> [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: Provider.of<AuthClass>(context).auth.inputData(),
              builder: ( context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.data}");
                } else {
                  return Text("Loading...");
                }
              },
            )
          ]
        )
      )
```

And this is the other part of my code which contains inputData():

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthClass {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void inputData()  async {
    final User? user =  _auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user!.uid;
    print(uid);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use Provider, you should modify your code as follow:

1. modify AuthClass:

```
class AuthClass extends ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<bool> inputData()  async {
    final User? user =  await _auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user!.uid;
    print(uid);
    return true;
  }
}
```

2. use it:

```
Provider.of<AuthClass>(context).inputData(), // .auth is redundant
```

3. make sure you have defined the provider in your main file:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthClass(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
```

also you should add `Provider` package to your dependency.

Comment: I have all done, but I'm having a last error for your second step when I removed the .auth: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: it is due to this fact that `future` in `FutureBuilder` needs a Future function, I have updated my answer (see step 1). I am assuming that `_auth.currentUser` is an async method because you have used `async` modifier for this function. you can check the result and return `true` or `false` based on your decision.

Comment: It works ! I have no more errors, the only thing is that it print the id on my console but in the screen of my have it print the text "true". Thank you for your time

Comment: It is because I have return a boolean in the provider, only as an example, you can return the received response or anything else. I would be grateful if you set my answer as an acceptable solution and vote it up if it helped you. @flomitri

Comment: No problem :) ! But how you return the received response because I tried `return _auth.currentUser.uid` but it's not working, I'm really debutant and I changed bool to String

Comment: `return _auth.currentUser.uid` is not correct, because this is a `async` process. you should use `return await _auth.currentUser.uid;` or first use `String temp = await _auth.currentUser.uid` and then `return temp;`